# How can I get packed variadic type?

Tags: c++

```
template<class... ArgumentType>
    class IEvent
    {
    public:

        virtual ~IEvent() = default;
        virtual bool Dispatch(ArgumentType...) = 0;
    };

    // Event Interfaces Impl
    class IMouseEvent : public IEvent<TypeMouseEvent, int, int>
    {
    public:
        IMouseEvent() : IEvent() { }
        virtual ~IMouseEvent() { }

        // override to get mouse event.
        virtual bool LMouseUp(unsigned x, unsigned y) { return true; }
        virtual bool LMouseDown(unsigned x, unsigned y) { return true; }
        virtual bool RMouseUp(unsigned x, unsigned y) { return true; }
        virtual bool RMouseDown(unsigned x, unsigned y) { return true; }
        virtual bool MouseMove(unsigned x, unsigned y) { return true; }

        bool Dispatch(TypeMouseEvent Type, int x, int y) override;
    };

    class IKeyboardEvent : public IEvent<TypeKeyboardEvent, UINT_PTR>
    {
    public:

        IKeyboardEvent() : IEvent() { }
        virtual ~IKeyboardEvent() { }

        // override to get keyboard event.
        virtual bool vKeyDown(UINT_PTR vKeyCode) { return true; }
        virtual bool vKeyUp(UINT_PTR vKeyCode) { return true; }
        virtual bool KeyCode(UINT_PTR KeyCode) { return true; }

        bool Dispatch(TypeKeyboardEvent Type, UINT_PTR Key) override;
};

template<class EventType, class... ArguementType>
class IEventHandler
{
protected:
    // Cancelable Events
    std::vector<EventType*>              m_PreEvents;
    // None-Cancelable Events
    std::vector<EventType*>              m_Events;

public:

    void RegisterPreEvent(EventType* eventObject) { m_PreEvents.push_back(eventObject); }
    void RegisterEvent(EventType* eventObject) { m_Events.push_back(eventObject); }
    bool DispatchEvent(ArguementType... Arguments);
};

template <class EventType, class ... ArgumentType>
inline bool IEventHandler<EventType, ArgumentType...>::DispatchEvent(ArgumentType... Arguments)
{
    bool isSuccessed = true;

    auto tryDispatch = [Arguments...](auto begin, auto end, bool fKeepExcute) -> bool
    {
        for (auto Iterator = begin; Iterator != end; ++Iterator)
        {
            if ((*Iterator)->Dispatch(Arguments...) == false && fKeepExcute == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };

    if (tryDispatch(m_PreEvents.begin(), m_PreEvents.end(), false))
    {
        isSuccessed = true;
        tryDispatch(m_Events.begin(), m_Events.end(), true);
    }

    return isSuccessed;
}
```

I want to get ArgumentType from IMouseEvent or IKeyboardEvent from IEventHandler.

How can I get packed variadic template types from `IMouseEvent`?

Im actually using like `IMouseEventHandler : public IEventHandler<IMouseEvent, TypeMouseEvent, int, int>`

just like `class IMouseEventHandler : public IEventHandler<IMouseEvent>` to get packed variadic template types from `IMouseEvent` to syncronize with DispatchEvent. (not to make duplicated DispatchEvent method)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `How can I get packet variadic type`? please post a [mcve] of what you tried or what you would like to achieve.

Comment: That `IEventHandler` class template, how would you use it? It doesn't look like your code instantiates it anywhere. I suppose you have some kind of factory that produces `IEvent`-derived objects, but this doesn't really work for handlers, does it? Perhaps you want to have a single non-templated `EventHandler`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this code:

```
template<class... Args>
class IEvent
{
public:
    using event_type = IEvent;
};
template <typename , typename>
struct IEventHandlerImpl;
template <typename Event, typename... Args>
struct IEventHandlerImpl<Event, IEvent<Args...>> {
    Event event;
    bool DispatchEvent(Args... args) {
        return event.Dispatch(args...);
    }
};

template <typename EventType>
struct IEventHandler
     : IEventHandlerImpl <EventType, typename EventType::event_type>
{
};
```

You can take look at [this demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/c3VdYDWUEnvmHWGE)

Comment: I don't use perfect forwarding because your example doesn't use it

Comment: @JunRyoungJu it's not too complicated.  Only about 10 lines of code

Comment: @JunRyoungJu it has a simple usage. And It doesn't need virtual dispatch

Comment: You may simplify it with `template<class... Args>
IEvent<Args...> FindIEventType(const IEvent<Args...>&);` (declaration without implementation). *using* helper: `template <typename T> using FindIEventType_t = decltype(FindIEventType(std::declval<T>()))`, and finally `IEventHandlerImpl<EventType, FindIEventType_t<EventType>>`

Comment: Or even adding type directly in `IEvent`: [Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fqFswVWjhf1S2G29)

Comment: @Jarod42 the implementation was omitted with the demo, I added here by accident only, your latter approach is better